# Cocoa - OSX - How do I copy a date from one controller to another?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to copy an NSDate from a WindowController to an NSObject. I don't get any errors, but I also don't get a date. What am I doing wrong?

code:

MainWindowController:

```
if (self.itemPurchaseDate == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"0");
        date2 = [NSDate date];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"mwc - itemPurchaseDate: %@", self.itemPurchaseDate.stringValue);
        NSLog(@"mwc - item %@", self.itemTitle.stringValue);
        NSLog(@"1");
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy"];
        // Conversion of NSString to NSDate
        NSString *tempString = self.itemPurchaseDate.stringValue;
        date2 = [formatter dateFromString:tempString];
        NSLog(@"mwc - date2 %@", date2);
    }

    NSLog(@"MWC date2: %@", date2);
```

Object (Date Calculator):

```
- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
     NSLog(@"DateCalc incoming date2 1: %@", mwc.date2);
    if (self = [super init]) {
```

Logs:

```
 -[MainWindowController textViewDidChangeSelection:]
 -[MainWindowController refreshItems:]

 -[MainWindowController showPurchaseDateSheet:]
 mwc - itemPurchaseDate: Jan 29, 2014
 mwc - item Another Test
 1
 mwc - date2 2014-01-29 05:00:00 +0000
 MWC date2: 2014-01-29 05:00:00 +0000

 -[PurchaseDateSheetController sheetWillDisplay]

 -[DateCalculator init]
 DateCalc incoming date2 1: (null)
 DateCalc incoming date2 2: 2014-02-02 23:04:10 +0000
 DateCalc incoming date2 3: (null)
 DateCalc incoming date2 4: 2014-02-02 23:04:10 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point you are accessing the main window controller in the date calculator, it is being created, so how is the mwc object equal to anything? If you want to be able to access the object at the creation of the DateCalculator then perhaps have an init: method along the lines of initWithMainWindowControllerReference:(MainWindowController*)mwc so that the object is accessible? 
Without seeing more code, I can't see how the init method has a reference to mwc at all, but I'm guessing that it is a property of the DateCalculator that has not yet been set.

Comment: hmm. I see your point. Let me play around with your idea. Thank you very much for responding.

Comment: That's ok - glad to hear it helped :)